# Как разместить на html сайте разные элементы?

Tags: html

Мне надо разместить на мой простенький сайт разные привилегии. К примеру; форум, регистрация пользователей, система комментирования. Все кто знает как это сделать, прошу поделится со мной информацией, зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Тут одним HTML не обойтись. Это точно. Пишете программу, изучайте программирование. Если вы делаете сайт на готовой системе, там где не надо программировать, то просто вам надо прочитать документацию к тому движку.

Answer (score 0):

фигасе,

> простенький сайт - Форум, регистрация пользователей, система коментирования...

пользуйся готовыми системами: joomla, или юкоз или чет такое

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress тебе в помощь, там и форум, регистрацию и комментирования легко можно разместить и сайт из простенькего сразу станет не простеньким :)

[www.LiveTeach.ru](http://Liveteach.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Учить **PHP** (или альтернативы) или юзать **CMS** (система управления сайтами), там и привилегии раздаются и компоненты ставятся (форумы, чаты, гостевые, новости, комменты)
Самые популярные - **1С битрикс**, **NetCat**, ну и прочие.